# Isolating a <tr> in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to write some jQuery that will hide a tr if two of the td's contain an element with a certain class. Here is the markup.

```
<tr>
        <td>Name<i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></a></td>
        <td class="centered_text"><i class="icon-minus"></i></td>   
        <td class="centered_text"><i class="icon-minus"></i></td>
</tr>
```

So if the **last two td's contain** i.icon-minus hide the tr. Which I would do by adding a class to the tr and hidding it. Can anyone help me through this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write a simple filter like below,

> Which I would do by adding a class to the tr and hidding it. Can anyone help me through this?

```
$('#tableId tr').filter(function () {
   return $('.icon-minus', this).length == 2;
}).addClass('hide');
```

or Simply

```
$('#tableId tr').filter(function () {
   return $('.icon-minus', this).length == 2;
}).hide();
```

Comment: How would you make it so that it is only checking if the last 2 TDs have it though?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest (currently untested):

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('i.icon-minus').length == 2;
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7wKc8/).

To search only in the last two cells or, more precisely, to search only in cells that aren't the *first*:

```
$('tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).find('td:gt(0) i.icon-minus').length == 2;
}).hide();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7wKc8/1/).

References:

- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`:gt()` (greater-than) selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

Comment: I would suggest finding how many `td`'s there are, then making that `gt()` dynamic (just subtracting the length by 3). Just incase more td's are added in the future! Either way +1!

Answer (score 2):

You could combine a [Next Adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/) with [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [:last-child](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) to match the `<td>` elements, then use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to obtain the `<tr>` elements:

```
$("td:has(i.icon-minus) + td:has(i.icon-minus):last-child").parent().hide();
```

Comment: What if the last-child is a text node, not the td itself?

Comment: @Juan, `:last-child` does not take text nodes into account ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9c3Wa/)). And IIRC text nodes are not valid inside `<tr>` elements anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use the [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to check the number of td's inside that tr that has that class.  Using slice(-2) will always get you the last 2 td's [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').filter(function() {
        // return the if td's returned == 2
        return $('td', this).slice(-2).filter(function() {
            // return if the last two td elements has icon-minus as class
            return $('i', this).hasClass('icon-minus');
        }).length == 2;
    }).addClass('hideThis');
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kMGL4/

Comment: D'oh, I forgot about the `-2` option for `slice()`... +1 =)